# Is it possible to paint a WinForms control outside it's own region (effectively hiding it)?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Before you jump to conclusions and ask "Why don't you just `Hide()` the form?" let me explain.

I have the following:

1. A PDF Viewer control `PDFViewer`.
2. A form containing a TextBox `TextBoxForm`.
3. A parent form containing `PDFViewer` and `TextBoxForm` (with `Owner` property set to this parent).

`TextBoxForm` is an overlay to `PDFViewer` and should be hidden when outside the bounds of `PDFViewer`, which can happen if the user scrolls. Here's how I achieve that:

```
PDFViewer_OnScroll(object sender, HandledMouseEventArgs e){
    TextBoxForm.SetBounds(GetBounds(PDFViewer));
    TextBoxForm.Top = [some value];
}
```

Ìnside `TextBoxForm` I do the following:

```
    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMove(e);
        UpdateFormRegion(); // Offset bounds so it's relative to the form itself instead of the screen
        Invalidate();
    }
```

This works fine when `TextBoxForm` is completely or partially inside the bounds of `PDFViewer`, but as soon as it's moved completely outside, whichever part of `TextBoxForm` was rendered before will still be rendered (I assumed it's because Windows decides there is no need to re-paint the form, when it's not inside it's own bounds).

It's easy enough to make a check for when this happens, but the reason I don't want to call `TextBoxForm.Hide()` is because that causes the `TextBox` to lose focus.

Any way I can get the form hidden without losing focus?

Comment: Does the `TextBoxForm` have to be a Form or can it be a control of some kind? You could look at transparency.

Comment: Transparency usually means that it'll still capture clicks etc. - for all purposes I need the form to be completely hidden except for the loss of focus.

Comment: **Never a good idea to do such hack.** You are only hindering the evolution of Windows as it make it harder for Microsoft to keep Windows compatible with existing applications because people like you misuse the system. **Please, stop doing that.**

Comment: It does not make any sense at all to put the focus on an invisible control. Your application will not works properly as soon as the user click outside of that control or use TAB key or otherwise move the focus. In most case, you should avoid overlapping controls.

Comment: The idea is that it should lose focus to all the usual events, just not when it's moved outside of the bounds programatically. The proper solution would probably be to check when setting the bounds, get caret position and `Hide()` if outside bounds and `Focus()` + set caret position when it's back inside again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought of a possible solution (not a very elegant one, however):

```
if (Right < _bounds.Left || Left > _bounds.Right || Bottom < _bounds.Top || Top > _bounds.Bottom)
{
    Top = -20000;
    Left = -20000;
}
```

Basically, whenever the form is moved/resized I check if it is now completely outside the supplied bounds and move it way off screen if true.

A less "hacky" solution is still welcome.